# How to view information about TSA from signed pdf?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, signature, pdfsig

How to get information about TSA (Time Stamping Authority) if it was used for a timestamp when signing a PDF document, e.g. with LibreOffice Draw?

LibreOffice Draw only displays the time, it is not possible to distinguish whether it is from the TSA or the time from the PC, similarly when using pdfsig.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there an example pdf file somewhere?

Comment: I could only send privately, because the digital signature clearly identifies the person, I would not like to expose it publicly. But here is e.g. available state public signed document with timestamp - https://nukib.cz/download/uredni_deska/2022-05-30_varovani-smartmetering_final_1.0_podepsno.pdf It would also be possible to sign a document with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: And in this case it is timestamp from trusted certification authority, but I see only time not origin of timestamp.